# What are the External Libraries in a PyCharm project?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a bit confused on this and can't find a satisfactory answer searching elsewhere - everything is about *using* external libraries in some way or another.

In my PyCharm projects, I've got your project root directory, which contains a `venv`. This `venv` of course contains the python executable relative to the project, as well as the relevant `site-packages` and modules I've downloaded via `pip` or whatever.

But there's always an `External Libraries` section, that has it's *own* Python executable, `venv`, `.gitignore`, `site-packages`, etc.

Is this normal? What's the purpose of having two `venvs` in the same project?

Thanks!

Comment: External to your project (directory, git,...). Files you should not edit (usually, but for debugging we do)

Comment: In this case though some of the files in the `External Libraries` folder are referencing my project? Like the Python executable.

Comment: It is the contrary: your project file references external libraries. The notation is confusing, but "my project" is in this case just files you are responsible. "external libraries" are files available to your project (but usually installed externally, like python, standard library, or with pip/conda). If you debug your code, you may just to them. And both parts are what we usually refer to "project" (so the confusion): you need both components.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one venv normally in your Project
The other Python Executable should be the global one.
Normally you use a venv to keep track of the needed Packages for this specific project. So that you don't confuse other Packages with other projects or have dependency/Version Issues

If you want you can also use the global Installation of Python which would not create a venv

Comment: In my case the executable in `External Libraries` is actually the executable within  my `venv` from my project directory. I'm not sure why/how, as I have no memory of setting that. So you're saying the default should be that the 'local' executable should be in the project's `venv`, and then the `External Libraries` executable should be the global one? Should it have a separate `venv` as well?

Comment: @confused_nomad You just need to understand the concept not the details - venv is local from global packages capsulated (for projects) to have easier track of dependencies and versioncontrol of these. Also inside the venv you can easily call over pip downloaded executables. The Global one doesn't need a venv but can produce version conflicts because Package A needs Version 1 of B but Package C need version 2 of B. Pycharm creates automatically a `venv` but you can change that behaviour at project creation or later at any given time